# Roles instead of inheritance -- are many unused fields okay?

Tags: object-oriented-analysis

Much exists about a situation where for example you have for example User and Admins in real life. Rather than make Admin its own class inheriting from User, you only have User and Admin is a role. (I think there are better examples.) But my question is, an Admin might have a lot of other fields, like a list of systems it can access. It seems like if you choose to use roles, you would have user objects with many empty fields that would only be non-null if the role was set to Admin. Is this okay or is there a better way to implement than using roles?
**EDIT:**
An idea that was suggested: Make role not an enum but a class which holds the fields unique to the role. Does this sound reasonable?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Typically, unused fields in an object point to an object decomposition problem. The usual refactoring solution is to push those fields into the objects which use them, the `roles` in your example, and so make them first class objects rather than just identifiers.